# Is it possible to create unions of primitives in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I couldn't find anything on Google, but was wondering if there was a way I could make a union of primitives in OpenGL? Something similar to POV-Ray would be cool.

Comment: By unions of primitives do you mean constructive solid geometry? In OpenGL the only primitives are points, lines, and triangles so if you want to have unions of objects then you will need to define that calculation yourself and then triangulate the result to draw it.

Comment: Oh thanks man. I must've spent too much time in POV-Ray because I was thinking of cylinders as primitives heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCSG](http://opencsg.org/) sounds like it might do what you want:

> OpenCSG is a library that does image-based CSG rendering using OpenGL. OpenCSG is written in C++ and supports most modern graphics hardware using Microsoft Windows or the Linux operating system.
>
> CSG is short for Constructive Solid Geometry and denotes an approach to model complex 3D-shapes using simpler ones. I.e., two shapes can be combined by taking the union of them, by intersecting them, or by subtracting one shape of the other. The most basic shapes, which are not result of such a CSG operation, are called primitives. Primitives must be solid, i.e., they must have a clearly defined interior and exterior. By construction, a CSG shape is also solid then.
>
> Image-based CSG rendering (also z-buffer CSG rendering) is a term that denotes algorithms for rendering CSG shapes without an explicit calculation of the geometric boundary of a CSG shape. Such algorithms use frame-buffer settings of the graphics hardware, e.g., the depth and stencil buffer, to compose CSG shapes. OpenCSG implements a variety of those algorithms, namely the Goldfeather algorithm and the SCS algorithm, both of them in several variants.
>
> Raytracers such as PovRay have used CSG for shape modeling since long ago.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds exactly like the thing I should've been using.